# specify layout for device (ConfirmationsController) only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i would specify a **layout** for my device **ConfirmationsController**

in my main application view  **application.html.erb** there are this one

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style="height:0px !important">

      <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">

      <%if user_signed_in?%>

      <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
      <%= render 'layouts/sidemenu'%>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
      <%= render 'layouts/content'%>
      <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
      </div>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer'%>
      </div>
     <% else %>
     <%= render 'layouts/header2'%>
     <%= render 'layouts/content'%>
     <%end%>
     </body>
    </html>
```

i have create a layout views **application2.html.erb**  without  **sidemenu,header and footer**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html style="height:0px !important">


            <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini"> 
                 <%=render'layouts/content'%>
             </body>
      </html>
```

in my **ConfirmationsController** i put this one

```
     class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
         layout "application2"



     private

        def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
           create_path
        end
     end
```

but it don't work and i don't know why !!!

i would like that in my **confirmationsController** after my create_path execution my view page appear without sidemenu,header and footer

thank in advance

Comment: Is there any actions on the confirmations controller?
are you sure that your routes are pointing to those actions?

Comment: yes ...  i  just use my action for redirect on create_path ; and it redirect correctly but ignore my **layout "application2**  and apply again the **main layout which is **application.html.erb**  I deduced that my routes works , now What could be the problem ?

Comment: You have to place this `layout 'application'` on the controller that handles `create_path`

Comment: Thank you it work but it's not that i want really, i would like that if user after cliked on his confirmation mail , **confirmation controller** must redirect him on a form page which exist already in my app but without the layout for his first log in to the app, for the next log in after clicked on **create_path**  link the form can appear in a app with the  layout , it's why i put the second layout **application2.html.erb** in **ConfirmationsController** for do it , if it's not possible can you purpose another suggestion without to have to create two forms which do the same thing ? thanks

Comment: You can control the layout on a per action basis, just put `layout ...` inside that action. If I understand you correctly...